# One-Point Compactification

Tags: general-topology

I think most of my arguments are correct, but I'm stuck in the first part of the problem: Let $X$ be a topological space with topology $\tau$, and define $X^\infty$ to be $X\cup${$\infty$} where {$\infty$} is not in $X$. Define $\tau^\infty$ to be $\tau$ along with sets of the form $V\cup${$\infty$} where $V\subseteq X$ and $X-V$ is both closed and compact in $X$. Show that $\tau^\infty$ defines a topology on $X^\infty$, that $X$ is a subspace of $X^\infty$, and that $X^\infty$ is compact.

My attempt:

$\tau^\infty$ is a topology on $X^\infty$: Since $\tau^\infty$ contains all sets in $\tau$, it contains $\varnothing$, and since $X\subseteq X$ and $X-X=\varnothing$ is closed and compact in $X$, $X\cup${$\infty$}$\in\tau^\infty$. Now let {$U_i: i\in I$} be a collection of sets in $\tau^\infty$. Each $U_i$ either contains {$\infty$} or it doesn't. If {$\infty$} is not in $U_i$ for all $i\in I$, then $U_i\in\tau$ for all $i\in I$, and arbitrary unions and finite intersections of the $U_i$s are still open in $X$, so are in $\tau$, which implies arbitrary unions and finite interections of the $U_i$s are in $\tau^\infty$. If, on the other hand, {$\infty$} is in $U_j$ for some $j$, then $U_j = V\cup${$\infty$}. I'm stuck here. Any advice on how I should proceed?

$X$ is a subspace of $X^\infty$: Since the open sets of $X$ are open sets in $X^\infty$, we have that any open set in $X$ in the subspace topology is of the form $X\cap U$, where $U$ is open in $X$, so $\tau$ is the subspace topology on $X$

$X^\infty$ is compact: Let {$W_i: i\in I$} be an open cover for $X^\infty$. Then {$\infty$}$\in W_j$ for some $j\in I$, so $W_j = V\cup${$\infty$}. Since {$W_i: i\in I$} is an open cover for $X-V$ and $X-V$ is compact, there is a finite sub-cover {$W_k: k\in K$} of $X-V$. But then {$W_k: k\in K$}$\cup W_j$ is a finite sub-cover of $X^\infty$. So $X^\infty$ is compact.

Does anyone see any problems?

Comment: Have you tried googling `one point compactification proof'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stay Right what you did.

For complete the question we need see if $\{\infty\}$ is in $U_j = V_j \cup \{\infty\}$, then $X - V_j$ is closed and compact. We will use $V_i = U_i$ for $i \in I$ such that $U_i \in \tau$

With the Morgan's law we have: $ X - \cup_{i \in I} V_i = \cap_{i \in I}(X-V_i)$. How any arbritary intersection of closed sets are closed follow that $X - \cup_{i \in I} V_i$ is closed. Every closed subset of compact set is compact, then $X - \cup_{i \in I} V_i \subset X - V_j$ is also compact. So $\cup_{i \in I} V_i \cup \{\infty\} \in \tau^{\infty}$. But $\cup_{i \in I} U_i = \cup_{i \in I} V_i \cup \{\infty\}$.

When $I$ is finite, and $\{\infty\} \notin U_i$ for some $i$ then $\cap_{i \in I} U_i = \cap_{i \in I} V_i \in \tau^{\infty}$. Suppose $\{\infty\} \in U_i$ for all $i$. Then $X- \cap_{i \in I}V_i = \cup_{i \in I}(X - V_i)$. Every finite union of closed and compact are closed and compact, so the result follows.